# how to get data ajax c# mvc 5 with id

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display users with id Entity using Ajax.

This function in controller:

```
 public class UserRoleAPIController : Controller
{

   [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult UserByEntity(long Id)
    {
        IList<UserProfile> userClient = new List<UserProfile>();
        //file select

        var biz = new UserProfileBiz(context, MvcApplication.log);
        userClient = biz.GetUsersInRole(ConstsGlobalHSESuite.ROLE_CLIENT_ADMIN, Id);

        return Json(userClient.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
    #endregion
}
```

Function in View Ajax:

```
  $('select').on('change', function() {


                  $.ajax({
                         url: '/UserRoleAPI/UserByEntity/' + this.value  ,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        async: true,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });

    });
```

Function **GetUsersInRole** return list:

```
public List<UserProfile> GetUsersInRole(string roleName, long? Id = 0)
    {
        var query = from user in context.UserProfile
                    where user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Name == roleName)
                    select user;
        if (Id != 0)
        {
            query = from user in context.UserProfile
                    where user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Name == roleName) && user.CompanyEntity.EntityId == Id
                    select user;
        }

          return query.ToList();
    }
```

Result of request Get:

```
<hr>
```

- Request URL:
  http://localhost:11361/UserRoleAPI/UserByEntity/2?_=1528298452257
- Request Method: GET Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error Remote
- Address: [::1]:11361 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: 500 Internal Server means your server code is crashing. In your browser dev tools->network tab, check the specific ajax request and inspect the "Response" and you should be able to see more details about why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

**just add this line in my function GetUsersInRole**

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: did that fix the issue?  Are you trying to get data back to the controller

Comment: While this may have answered your specific question,  This does not sufficiently explain why, nor does the the question reflect the requirement for this configuration

Comment: Whilst I agree that it's low quality, it's not low-quality enough to deserve deletion. Looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what is going on, but that error could happen for a variety of reasons, namely:

- The request is setup incorrectly
- A framework component is failing to serve the request for some reason (possibly due to a customization)
- One of the object is null
- Something went wrong with the database

Without more precise info, we can't really troubleshoot further.